# ¿Como puedo guardar el resultado de una funcion en una variable en Python?

Tags: python, python-requests

Les cuento.
Estoy intentando guardar mi output que recibo al ejecutar una función la cual es la siguiente.

```
import os

def check_ping():
    response = os.system("ping -c 3 " + '192.168.0.1')

check_ping()
```

No encuentro la manera correcta de pasar el resultado de ese ping a una variable para luego mandarla a un archivo txt. El resultado al ejecutar esa funcion me lo muestra en pantalla y necesito que se vaya a un archivo de texto pero que lo haga desde el codigo y no yo desde la consola.
Saludos!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Considera primero no usar `os.system`, en la práctica se considera obsoleto en favor de [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#module-subprocess). En este caso `subprocess.run` es más que suficiente.

Si quieres almacenar el resultado de la salida estándar del proceso en una variable, puedes hacer simplemente que la función retorno dicha salida.

```
import subprocess

def check_ping():
    response = subprocess.run(["ping", "-c", "3", "192.168.0.1"],
                              capture_output=True,
                              text=True
                              )
    return response.stdout

response = check_ping()

with open("ping.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write(response)
```